# Home network: configure for IPv6

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ipv6

I want to configure my home network to be able to access the Internet via IPv6, because I want to learn what it takes, and I want to be a part of reducing demand (eventually) for IPv4 addresses.

My ISP does not support IPv6 yet (YourLink, Saskatchewan, Canada), so I signed up for a tunnel through Hurricane Electric.  I run an Untangle firewall, so I'm thinking my first step is to configure that correctly.  Once my IPv4 devices can translate to IPv6 at the firewall, my goal is to move the translation incrementally closer to my devices, until the day when all of my devices are accessing the Internet natively using IPv6.

Where do I start?  Are there tutorials out there?  I am not a network engineer, but I have moderate experience configuring my home network under IPv4.  I am comfortable with DHCP and routing/port forwarding.

Comment: “my IPv4 devices can translate to IPv6 at the firewall” – That’s not how it works. Every device needs a IPv6 address. I’m not familiar with your firewall appliance, so I cannot help you. But I’m sure they already have a tutorial for exactly what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Well, after researching a little I get the impression that supporting tunnel brokers is not a priority for Untangle. So you’ll have to switch to another firewall or set up an additional box to handle the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate protocols. Your router will not automatically convert between them.

There is not a lot to this. Most OSes now default to having IPv6 enabled. Your hosts with IPv6 will prefer to use IPv6 if the other end does, and they will use IPv4 if the other end does not.

You configure your end of the tunnel on your router. I'm not familiar with your particular router model, but I have done this on several router models.

After that, you just enable IPv6 on your hosts. There are plug-ins for some browsers which will show you which protocol is being used for different web sites to which you are connected.

This should be transparent to you.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the Untangle firewall supports IPv6 tunneling.  If you can configure Untangle to pass Protocol 41, you should be able run your tunnel to a device inside the firewall.  (You will need to firewall IPv6 separately.)

I did my initial IPv6 firewall on OpenWRT running on a wifi router.  OpenWRT will run on a wide variety of low cost routers.  This includes an IPtables  firewall as part of the router software.  If it is possible to put a router between your ISPs router and the Untangle firewall, it appears the Untangle firewall can be used to firewall IPv6.)

I went through a few stages:

- [IPv6 over 6to4](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/) which was reasonably reliable for outgoing traffic, but not for incoming traffic.
- [IPv6 over 6in4 (HE tunnel)](https://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/) which is quite reliable for incoming and outgoing traffic.
- I haven't posted yet on my configuration where the tunnel is hosted on an Ubuntu server, although some of the configuration is included in my second article.

The main difference between the OpenWRT router and the Ubuntu solution is how the tunnel is configured.  The Hurricane Electric site has examples for a number of operating systems.